# Python: loop doesn't break

Tags: python, loops, break

Having problem with breaking the loop. I want to break it when it reach the end word. Hopefully you can help me what's I'm missing on this code. Thank you.

```
def y():
    with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
        x = list()
        for line in rf:
            if 'config system global' in line:
                x.append('config system global\n')
                while True:
                    x.append(rf.__next__())
                    if 'end\n' in line:
                        break

                    with open('test.txt', 'w') as wf:
                        wf.writelines(x)


config system global
    set admin-maintainer disable
    set admin-scp enable
    set admin-server-cert "Fortinet_Firmware"
    set admintimeout 15
    set anti-replay disable
    set fgd-alert-subscription advisory latest-threat
    set gui-dynamic-routing enable
    set gui-multiple-utm-profiles enable
    set gui-replacement-message-groups enable
    set gui-sslvpn-personal-bookmarks enable
    set gui-sslvpn-realms enable
    set gui-wireless-opensecurity enable
    set hostname "XXXXXX"
    set internal-switch-mode interface
    set revision-backup-on-logout enable
    set revision-image-auto-backup enable
    set strong-crypto enable
    set tcp-timewait-timer 120
    set timezone 80
    set vdom-admin enable
end
config system accprofile
    edit "prof_admin"
        set admingrp read-write
        set authgrp read-write
        set endpoint-control-grp read-write
        set fwgrp read-write
        set loggrp read-write
        set mntgrp read-write
        set netgrp read-write
        set routegrp read-write
        set sysgrp read-write
        set updategrp read-write
        set utmgrp read-write
        set vpngrp read-write
        set wanoptgrp read-write
        set wifi read-write
```

Comment: BTW your last statement writes the file at each iteration. Not very efficient (de-indent it!)

Comment: what is your test data?

Comment: I tried to de-indent it. It doesn't create a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the internal `while` loop:

```
while True:
    x.append(rf.__next__())
    if 'end\n' in line:
        break
```

it's an infinite loop, because `line` doesn't change within the loop. It probably ends with `StopIteration` exception unless it's catched

The proper code would be:

```
while True:
    line = rf.__next__()
    if 'end\n' in line:
        break
    x.append(line)
```

append before or after the test for `end` depending on whether you want to keep the `end` in the block.

and de-indent:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.writelines(x)
```

at the same level as the other `with` block, or the file will be written at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re module`.

**Ex:**

```
import re        
for line in s.split("\n"):
    if re.match('end', line):
        break
```

Comment: The question was edited. The data was posted earlier

Comment: this isn't the issue OP is having.